# problem with jquery's clone in IE and Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, clone, dom-manipulation

I am trying to copy the masterdiv contents including child divs. Below is the code implementation.

```
<label id="lblMessage" />
<table width="100%">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="colorSelector">
                <div style="background-color: rgb(0, 0, 255);" />
            </div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="dynPageContent"></div>
            <input type="button" id="updContent" value="Update" />
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    $(document).ready(
    function() {
        $('#colorSelector').ColorPicker({
            color: '#0000ff',
            onShow: function(colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeIn(500);
                return false;
            },
            onHide: function(colpkr) {
                $(colpkr).fadeOut(500);
                return false;
            },
            onChange: function(hsb, hex, rgb) {
                $('#dynPageContent div').css('backgroundColor', '#' + hex);
            }
        });
        if ($("#dynPageContent").length) {
            $("#dynPageContent").html('<%= Model.Page_Content.Trim() %>');
            if ($("#pageContent").length) {
                $("#pageContent").load("/Home/PageContent");
            }
            if ($("#Sidebar").length) {
                $("#Sidebar").load("/Home/Sidebar");
            }
        }

        $('#updContent').unbind('click');
        $('#updContent').click(function(e) {
            var updatedpageContent = $('<div />').append($('#dynPageContent div[id^="pageContent"],div[id^="sideba"]').clone()).remove().html();
            $.getJSON("/Home/UpdatePage/?t=" + new Date(), { pc: updatedpageContent },
            function(data) {
                if (data != null) {
                    if (data == true) {
                        $('#lblMessage').html("Page template updated.");
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I am loading the html/divs(place holders for the content) from the database and i can change the background color of the child divs and update the placeholders/child divs with new style(background color) to the database using json.

The above code works fine in Firefox, but in IE and chrome, the masterdiv(`dynPageContent`) disappears.

Whats wrong with the above code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i got it solved.

The problem is with the html tag of label.

I have replaced

```
<label id="lblMessage" />
```

with

```
<label id="lblMessage"></label>
```

That solved the problem. Strange one..